# Prime factorization - C

Tags: c, functional-programming, primes

After learning [prime factorization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGbOiYhHY2c) today, below is the C code written,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define FIRST_PRIME 2
typedef enum {false, true}bool;

bool isEvenlyDivide(int compositeNumber, int number){
  return (compositeNumber % number)? false:true;
}

int findOtherFactor(int compositeNumber, int number){
  return compositeNumber / number;
}

bool isPrime(int wholeNumber){
  int factorLimit = wholeNumber / 2;
  for(int isItFactor = 2; isItFactor <= factorLimit; isItFactor++){
    if(isEvenlyDivide(wholeNumber, isItFactor)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool isComposite(int wholeNumber){
  return !isPrime(wholeNumber);
}

int findNextPrime(int primeNumber){
  int number = primeNumber+1;
  if(isPrime(number)){
    return number;
  }
  return findNextPrime(number);
}

void findPrimeFactors(int compositeNumber, int primeNumber){

  if(isEvenlyDivide(compositeNumber, primeNumber)){

    printf("%d ", primeNumber);
    int otherFactor = findOtherFactor(compositeNumber, primeNumber);
    if(isComposite(otherFactor)){
      findPrimeFactors(otherFactor, FIRST_PRIME);
    }else{
      printf("%d ", otherFactor);
    }
  }else{

    int nextPrime = findNextPrime(primeNumber);
    findPrimeFactors(compositeNumber, nextPrime);
  }

  return;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

  int compositeNumber = atoi(argv[1]);

  if(argc == 1){
    printf("usage: \n");
    printf("% ./findPrimeFactors <someCompositeNumber>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  findPrimeFactors(compositeNumber, FIRST_PRIME);
}
```

---

for which, below is the compilation and execution(in cygwin),

```
Personal-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/recursion
$ gcc dummy.c -o findPrimeFactors

Personal-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/recursion
$ ./findPrimeFactors 29
29 1
Personal-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/recursion
$ ./findPrimeFactors 116
2 2 29
Personal-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/recursion
$ ./findPrimeFactors 16
2 2 2 2
Personal-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/recursion
$ ./findPrimeFactors 14
2 7
```

---

1. Do you think the code is complete from conceptual and implementation
   aspect?
2. If yes, Can we further make this code, elegant & high perform?
3. If yes, Can I make it a stateless functional program using C?

**Note**: It took 15 minutes for me to write this program

Comment: Am also accepting prime numbers from this program, which is not required

Comment: What do you intend to accomplish by stating that it took 15 minutes to write the program?

Comment: @skiwi Intention is to know, What would be the maximum time required by a good programmer, to write this program with elegance and efficiency? Because I need to know, where I stand in programming world? by sharing my computer program? Hope I clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doing `cond?false:true` is very odd to see and very much prone to mistakes in writing or reading. It's better to use negation in the condition:

```
bool isEvenlyDivide(int compositeNumber, int number){
  return (compositeNumber % number) == 0;
}
```

You can reduce the number of checks you do by using the knowledge that you only need to check prime factors up to the square root of `wholeNumber`, all but one prime is odd:

```
if(isEvenlyDivide(wholeNumber, 2)){
  return false;
}
for(int isItFactor = 3; isItFactor*isItFactor <= wholeNumber; isItFactor+=2)
    if(isEvenlyDivide(wholeNumber, isItFactor)){
      return false;
    }
}
```

That can also be used for `findNextPrime`, speaking of recursion isn't the best way to describe looping until you find something instead prefer an explicit loop:

```
int findNextPrime(int primeNumber){

    int number = primeNumber+1;
    if(isEvenlyDivide(primeNumber, 2)){
      number ++;
    }
    while(!isPrime(number)){
        number+=2;
    }
    return number;
}
```

When looping over all primes you can make use of the previous primes you have found to skip the non-primes. This can be done using the for example [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: `number+=2`, why are your sure that next prime is 2 numbers away?

Comment: Because all primes except 2 are odd.